# Convert a PostGIS 2D polygon to a 3D Polyhedralsurface using C#

Tags: postgis, 3d, polyhedralsurface

I'm trying to convert a 2D polygon into a 3D polyhedralsurface because i will use the surface to do a Intersect with other 3D geometries.

The problem is when im trying to create the surface from a polygon, building all the sides i constantly get the error
"PolyhedralSurface is invalid : inconsistent orientation of PolyhedralSurface detected at edge x"

Here is my C# code for converting the polygon:

```
    private string ConvertPolygonToSurface(Region3 region)
    {
        int spread = 10;
        var polyList = new List<Region3>();

        //Create Top
        var topPolygonRing = new Ring3();
        for (int i = region.Shell.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
            topPolygonRing.Add(new Vector3(region.Shell[i].x, region.Shell[i].y, spread ));
        polyList.Add(new Region3(topPolygonRing));

        //Create sides
        for (int i = 0; i < region.Shell.Count; i++)
        {
            //Skip the last point of the shell
            if (i != region.Shell.Count-1)
                polyList.Add(CreateSidePiece(region.Shell[i], region.Shell[i+1], spread));
        }

        //Create bottom
        var bottomPolygonRing = new Ring3();
        for (int i = 0; i < region.Shell.Count; i++)
            bottomPolygonRing.Add(new Vector3(region.Shell[i].x, region.Shell[i].y, spread *-1));
        polyList.Add(new Region3(bottomPolygonRing));
        
        return ConvertPolygonlistToPolyhedralsurfaceWkt(polyList);
    }


    private Region3 CreateSidePiece(Vector3 point1, Vector3 point2, int spreed)
    {
        var ring = new Ring3();
        ring.Add(new Vector3(point1.x, point1.y, spreed * -1));
        ring.Add(new Vector3(point1.x, point1.y, spreed));
        ring.Add(new Vector3(point2.x, point2.y, spreed));
        ring.Add(new Vector3(point2.x, point2.y, spreed * -1));
        ring.Add(new Vector3(point1.x, point1.y, spreed * -1));

        return new Region3(ring);
    }



    private string ConvertPolygonlistToPolyhedralsurfaceWkt(IList<Region3> polygonList)
    {
        var result = "POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z(";

        foreach (var polygon in polygonList)
            result += WkbTools.ToWkt(polygon).Replace("POLYGON", "") + ",";

        return result.Remove(result.Length-1, 1) + ")";
    }
```

Any suggestions how to make sure the surface is consistent?